# Merge 2 data frames so that each have same number of columns

Tags: r, dataframe, merge

I have loaded a data set from a csv file as :

```
data <- read.csv("data.csv", header = FALSE)
```

I segregated `data` into sets as follows:

```
d3 = training_data[785,data[785,] %in% c(3)]
d5 = training_data[785,data[785,] %in% c(5)]
```

Now the number of rows in `d3` are equal to `d5` but they in the number of columns. `d3` and `d5` both have 100 and 200 columns respectively. I want to create equal set for both. So I need a new data frame, let us say `d_3_5` where both `d3` and `d5` have 100 columns each. How could I do this?

Comment: Your desired output is quite vague. What is your criteria for selecting the columns?

Comment: @lmo I want to take 100 columns from `d3` and 100 from `d5` and merge them to one data frame.

Comment: It would have been better if you shared reproducible data.

Comment: @lmo As you would see in the snippet given, `d3` comprises of the data frame where the value in ith column of 785th row was `3`. Same for `d5`. Now since they are different in number, I want to create a data frame where I could have both of them but both having equal number of columns

Comment: @RanaUsman It is a huge dataset. 785 rows and 85K columns. I could help answer your queries though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to merge using a function called `cbind`. Here is what I did:

```
data <- read.csv("data.csv", header = FALSE)
d3 = training_data[785,data[785,] %in% c(3)]
d5 = training_data[785,data[785,] %in% c(5)]

d_3_5 = cbind(d3, d5[1:100,])
```

This created a new data frame with equal share from `d3` and `d5`.